# is it possible to unittest a service without having to initialise all constructor services

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I've a easy question (for most) regarding testing with Jasmine in angular.
is it possible to test a service, without having to initialize all constructor services?

Because i would like to use the service class as a mock (like [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/#_mock_by_using_a_real_instance_with_spy)),
but initializing all services would be a lot of extra work.